# Sum of $\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}$ over divisors

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I am wondering if $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}$ (which evaluates to $1/k$ for $d=p^k$ and $0$ otherwise) has any interesting significances or bounds.

For $n = p_1^{k_1}\dots p_s^{k_s}$, we would have

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)} = \sum_i H_{k_i}$$
where $H_k$ is the $k$-th harmonic number, but is there a good way to approximate this?

Here is the plot for $(n, \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)})$ for $1\le n \le 50000$:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking for an asymptotic expansion? No statements can be made about the values for individual $n$.

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, it is generally useful to follow up with people who ask you for clarification.

Comment: @MiloMoses Sorry I wasn't online last night. Yes I am looking for asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Do you mean bounds ? Look at your plot it is obvious the sequence doesn't have any simple asymptotic, that's what happens in most cases with Dirichlet convolutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example derive the inequalities
$$
\sum\limits_{d|n} {\frac{{\Lambda (d)}}{{\log d}}} = \sum\limits_i {H_{k_i } }  \le \sum\limits_i {(\log (k_i  + 1) + \gamma )}  = \log d(n) + \omega (n)\gamma 
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{d|n} {\frac{{\Lambda (d)}}{{\log d}}} = \sum\limits_i {H_{k_i } }  \ge \sum\limits_i {\log (k_i  + 1)}  = \log d(n).
$$
Here $\gamma$ is the Euler$-$Mascheroni constant, $d(n)$ is the divisor function and $\omega(n)$ counts each distinct prime factor of $n$. In particular,
$$
\log 2 \le \mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\log \log n}}{{\log n}} \sum\limits_{d|n} {\frac{{\Lambda (d)}}{{\log d}}}  \le \log 2 + \gamma .
$$

Comment: I'm confused. At primes $p$ we have that $\sum_{d|p}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}=1$, and thus it does not satisfy your estimate. You replaced $d(n)$ and $\omega(n)$ with their asymptotic expansions, which does not say anything about individual values.

Comment: @MiloMoses The inequalities give $$0.69\ldots = \log 2 = \log d(p) \le \sum\nolimits_{d|p} {\frac{{\Lambda (d)}}{{\log d}}}  \le \log d(p) + \omega (p)\gamma  = \log 2 + \gamma=1.27\ldots.$$ The final result is a $\limsup$ and not a $\lim$.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I mistook the limsup for the classic ($c_0<\liminf<\limsup<c_1$)

Answer (score 0):

We can begin by computing

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n<N}\sum_{d|n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}&=\sum_{d<N}\sum_{n<N/d}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}\\
&=\sum_{d<N}\left[\frac{N}{d}\right]\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}\\
&=\sum_{p<N}\left[\frac{N}{p}\right]+O\left(\sqrt{N}\right)\\
&=\sum_{p<N}\frac{N}{p}+O(\pi(N))\\
&=\sum_{p<N}\frac{N}{p}+O\left(\frac{N}{\log(N)}\right)\\
&=N\left(\log(\log(N))+M+O\left(\frac{1}{\log(N)}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{N}{\log(N)}\right)
\end{align*}

Here, the last estimate is from Merten's third theorem with "simple" error bounds (i.e not dependent on PNT). Thus,

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n<N}\sum_{d|n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}{\log(d)}=\log(\log(N))+M+O\left(\frac{1}{\log(N)}\right)$$

without PNT